# Segfault with SDL_BlitSurface() in loop

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, sdl

I was given a `char *map` that contains the different elements that you can find on screen. Those elements are `e`, for electricity, `c`, for coin, and `_`, for empty space.

I've done a loop that will go through the array and will detect whenever I have one of those characters. Here's the problem though, when I look to blit the corresponding sprite for each letter my program segfaults.

When I took out `SDL_BlitSurface()` the program works correctly, doing the amount of loops necesary.

I feel that I'm missing something before `SDL_BlitSurface()`

Here's the function where everything goes wrong:

```
void            print_map()
{
  int           i;
  SDL_Rect      pos;
  int           x;
  int           y;


  if ((th_client[1].coin = IMG_Load("./images/coin.png")) == NULL)
    printf("Erreur\n");  
  y = 0;
  i = 0;
  while (y != 10)
    {
      pos.y = (y * 10) + 5;
      x = 0;
      while (x != 95)
        {
          pos.x = (x * 10) + 5;
          printf("pos x: %d\n", pos.x);
          if (th_client[1].map[i] == 'c')
            {
              printf("char : %c\n", th_client[1].map[i]);
              if ((SDL_BlitSurface(th_client[i].screen, NULL,th_client[i].coin, &pos)) == -1) // <- it blows up right here
                printf("Erreur\n");
            } 
          x++;
          i++;
        }
      y++;
      printf("y : %d\n", y);
    }
  SDL_FreeSurface(th_client[1].coin);
}
```

th_client[1] corresponds to the graphics thread, inside there's I've got a structure with everything needed to initialize SDL.

Output:

```
pos x: 5
...
pos x: 945
y : 1 // <- jumps into the next line
pos x: 5
...
pos x: 355
char : c // <- Coin found
Segmentation fault
```

Comment: Have you looked at `SDL_GetError()`? The documentation says "Returns 0 if the blit is successful or a negative error code on failure; call SDL_GetError() for more information."

Comment: I get no errors when using `SDL_GetError`, I'll edit my post with the output I ge.t

Comment: Does `th_client` have enough elements? (Based on your loop, that would be 950.) You're also blitting `th_client[i].coin`, but you only load `th_client[1].coin`

Comment: That was it! I can't beleive I completely went over that part hundreds of times and I never even noticed I was putting i instead of 1. Thanks man.